# Why a NPE in 2d Array?

Tags: java, multidimensional-array, nullpointerexception

Why do I get an NPE on the assignment of:

```
    mPyramid[row][column] = temp;
```

Here is my code:

```
    Block temp;
    Block[][] pyramid = new Block[mInput.length][];

    for (int i = 0; i < pyramid.length; i++) {
        pyramid[i] = new Block[mInput[i].length];
        for (int j = 0; j < pyramid[i].length; j++) {
            pyramid[i][j] = new Block();
        }
    }

    for (int row = 1; row < mInput.length; row++) {
        for (int column = 0; column < mInput[row].length; column++) {
            temp = new Block(mInput[row][column], null, null);
            mPyramid[row][column] = temp;

            setParents(row, column);
            temp.setPathNode(calculateDistance(temp));

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't see any declaration of `mPyramid`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you're creating the local variable `pyramid` and then referencing `mPyramid`.

Comment: thanks, just needed a 2nd pair of eyes to see that.  Will be accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

Because either `mPyramid` is not initialised or the subarray `mPyramid[row]` isn't initialised.

I guess you are in the second case. To initialise mPyramid immediately with a height and width you can use:

```
mPyramid = new Block[height][width]; // Swap height and width if you prefer
```